# How to upgrade python2 to python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, homebrew

I'm using macbook on arm processor.
And I tried to upgrade python2 to python3, but I don't know how to do it.
I'm using homebrew and I installed both python2 and python3 through homebrew.
I typed a command like that.

```
python -v => python 2.7.16
python3 --version => python3.9.1
python2 --version => python 2.7.16
```

Comment: Everything seems to be fine. It is normal to use `python3` to run Python 3.

Comment: Everything fine. If you want to point `python` to `python3.9.1` you can: a) define shell alias, b) change `$PATH`, c) start using virtualenv/pipenv/poetry to create isolated python environment (as everybody does)

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a question

Comment: It not's clear what you're asking, but don't touch the system's `python` installation. Just use `python3` wherever you need it or use a virtual environment, so that in there you can simply use `python`.